# ImageIO.write changing colors

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I am using Java to save and read pictures and I need each pixel to be exactly the color it was saved as but whenever I use `ImageIO.write` some of the pixels are off ever so slightly. For example, one pixel might change from `rgb(145, 182, 110)` to `rgb(141, 184, 114)`. I have tried writing the picture to JPEGs, PNGs, and BMPs but the pixels always get changed slightly. Is there a way to make this not happen?

Edit: here is the code where I save the image. I have the pixels that I want saved in a 2D array of Pixels called pix.

```
BufferedImage b=new BufferedImage(pix.length, pix[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
String name = JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("What do you want to call the file?");

for(int r=0;r<pix.length;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<pix[r].length;c++){
        b.setRGB(c, r, new Color(pix[r][c].getRed(),pix[r][c].getGreen(),pix[r][c].getBlue()).getRGB());
    }
}
File f1 = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name + ".bmp");
try {
        f1.createNewFile();
        ImageIO.write(b, "bmp", f1);
} catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should post your code so that we can see what exactly you are talking about, and hopefully help you find an answer.

Comment: You're missing the part where you read the image. Like I said, please create a [mcve]. This code needs to read the image and then write it. And before you post that, test if it also has the same problem you've mentioned.

Comment: of course you have to choose the wierd type 3BYTE_BGR - why? are you some kind of hacker??

Comment: I tried others and they all gave me the same problem. That was just the last one I tried. I can change that if it solves some problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's the saving that is changing the pixels? Have you tried examining `pix` before saving to see whether it contains `145,182,110` or `141,184,114`?

Comment: It isn't changing the value in the array, it is changing the color in the image once saved. The value in the array is the same before and after.

Comment: what is Pixel is some kind of class? can you post the whole program from top to bottom?

Comment: @gpasch What do you think is weird about `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`? There's nothing wrong with using it, in fact it's very common...